# When will readObjectNoData be called

Tags: java, serialization

I am reading Effective Java Item74. And I am interesting in the serialization of java object. But one method "readObjectNoData" just got me confused.

Here is the explanation of JavaDoc

> For serializable objects, the readObjectNoData method allows a class to control the initialization of its own fields in the event that a subclass instance is deserialized and the serialization stream does not list the class in question as a superclass of the deserialized object. This may occur in cases where the receiving party uses a different version of the deserialized instance's class than the sending party, and the receiver's version extends classes that are not extended by the sender's version. This may also occur if the serialization stream has been tampered; hence, readObjectNoData is useful for initializing deserialized objects properly despite a "hostile" or incomplete source stream.

It says when I serialize an object, it is older version which does not extend a parent class, but when I deserialize, the class upgraded to a new version and extends some other class.

I really want to play with this. So I have a Employee class

```
public class Employee implements Serializable { //v1
  public String name;
  public int age;
  protected String address;
  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public Employee()
  {
    name= "John";
    age = 1;
    address ="N/A";
  }

  public Employee(String name , int age, String address)
  {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    this.address = address;
  }
}
```

And a Serialization class

```
public class Se {
    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Employee e = new Employee();

        try {
            FileOutputStream fileOut =
                new FileOutputStream("tmp.txt");
            ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOut);
            out.writeObject(e);
            out.close();
            fileOut.close();
            System.out.printf("Serialized data is saved in tmp.txt");
        }catch(IOException i) {
            i.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

After I serialized a Employee object to tmp.txt, I change the Employee class

```
public class Employee extends Person { //v2
  protected String address ;
  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
  public Employee()
  {
    super();
    address ="N/A";
  }

  public Employee(String name , int age, String address)
  {
    super(name,age);
    this.address = address;
  }
  private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {
      name = "John";
      age = 1;
  }
}
```

Here is my Person class

```
class Person implements Serializable{
  protected String name;
  protected int age;

  Person() {
    this("John",1);
  }
  Person(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
  }
}
```

When I deserialized by my Deserialized class

```
public class De {
  public static void main(String [] args) {
    Employee e = null;
    try {
      FileInputStream fileIn = new FileInputStream("tmp.txt");
      ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(fileIn);
      e = (Employee) in.readObject();
      in.close();
      fileIn.close();
    }catch(IOException i) {
      i.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("IOException");
      return;
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException c) {
      System.out.println("Employee class not found");
      c.printStackTrace();
      return;
    }

    System.out.println("Deserialized Employee...");
    System.out.println("Name: " + e.name);
    System.out.println("Address: " + e.address);
    System.out.println("Age: " + e.age);
  }
}
```

The output always shows

```
Deserialized Employee...
Name: null
Address: N/A
Age: 0
```

And even when I set debug points inside readObjectNoData method, it is never triggered, I cannot find any runnable example online so I provided so many code here. Does anyone know what did I miss?

Any comments would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a unique case where deserializer of the class has a version of the class (Employee) that is based on a subclass (Person).

The subclass can say "it's ok if my base class is **not** in the serialized data - just make an empty one.

> Edit below

Try these two version for "Deserialization". I mean serialize your v1 employee and then try below:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
public class Employee extends Person implements Serializable { //v2
  protected String address ;
  static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  public Employee()
  {
    super();
    address ="N/A";
  }

  public Employee(String name , int age, String address)
  {
    super(name,age);
    this.address = address;
  }

}
```

> Person

```
import java.io.ObjectStreamException;
import java.io.Serializable;

class Person implements Serializable{
   protected String name;
   protected int age;

   Person() {

 }

Person(String name, int age) {
   this.name = name;
   this.age = age;
}
private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException {

  name = "cccc";
  age = 1;
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }
}
```

You shall see an exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at test.serialization.Person.readObjectNoData(Person.java:26)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObjectNoData(ObjectStreamClass.java:1089)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1955)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at test.serialization.De.main(De.java:22)
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But if I change the content of readObjectNoData method to
name= "Bo";
age = 50;

The deserialization will also show John, N/A, 1 which means the readObjectNoData is not triggered. In which occasion will that function being triggered?

Comment: Edited the answer to show complete stack trace. for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for your help. So the readObjectNoData should write in superclass and the superclass should implement Serialization

Comment: Is it possible, using a ClassLoader, to do this test all in one run?